# Let $R = \mathbb F_3[X]/\langle X^3 + X^2 + 1\rangle$ and $\alpha = [X] \in R$. Show $R^*$ is not cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

> Let $R = \mathbb F_3[X]/\langle X^3 + X^2 + 1\rangle$ and $\alpha = [X] \in R$. Show $R^*$ is not cyclic.

**I've proven:**

$X^3+ X^2 + a \in \mathbb F_3[X]$ is irreducible $\iff$ $a=2$.

$\alpha \in R^*$ and ord($\alpha$)=$8$ with respect to the group $(R^*, \cdot)$.

$\alpha^4$ and $-\alpha^4$ are two different elements in $R^*$ and ord($\alpha^4$)=ord($-\alpha^4$)=$2$ with respect to the group $(R^*, \cdot)$.

**To prove:**

$R^*$ is not cyclic.

**Ideas:**

I know $|R|=3^3 = 81$ and $R$ is not a field. The numbers $2$ and $8$ divides |R^*|, $|R^*| > 8$ which implies $|R^*| = 8k$ for $2 \le k \le 10$. $\mathbb F_3 \cong \{0,1,2\} \in R$.

I find these cyclic exercises very difficult, are there some general guidelines in solving them ?

Comment: Point 1 : It is necessary that yo have to write what you have tried but it is sufficient to write what you have tried which is "related" to given question.. I do not really understand how "$X^3+X^2+a∈F_3[X]$ is irreducible $⟺ a=2$" is relevant to the question...

Comment: Point No 2 : your notations are so confusing.. I doubt if any other user can understand what does $2,8 \mid |R^*| \land |R^*| > 8 $ mean...

Comment: It means $2$ and $8$ divides the order of $R^*$ and the order of $R^*$ is greater than 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $G$ be a cyclic group, then every subgroup of $H \le G$ is also cyclic by a theorem that should sound familiar to most people.

Let $H = \{\alpha^4, -\alpha^4, 1,-1\} \subseteq R^*$. Then by verification $H$ is indeed a subgroup of $(R^*, \cdot)$, since $1 \in H, (\alpha^4)^{-1} \in H, (-\alpha^4)^{-1} \in H$ and for any two elements in $H$ the product also lies in $H$ (ie. $\pm \alpha^8 = \pm 1$ .

Now in the question above it has been proved that the order of $\alpha^4$ and $-\alpha^4$ is $2$. By looking at $-1$ we see it has order $2$ also. The order of $1$ is $1$.

Thus no element in $H$ has order 4, which implies by contraposition, $R^*$ cannot be cyclic, since it has a subgroup which is **not** cyclic.

Answer (score 1):

You have already seen that $X^3 + X^2 + 1$ is reducible: $X^3 + X^2 + 1 = (X + 2)(X^2 + 2X + 2)$ with $X^2 + 2X + 2$ being irreducible. This allows you to complete determine $R$ and also $R^*$.

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, $R \cong {\mathbb F}_3[X]/(X + 2) \times {\mathbb F}_3[X]/(X^2 + 2X + 2)$, so $R \cong {\mathbb F}_3 \times {\mathbb F}_9$. Therefore $R^* \cong {\mathbb F}_3^* \times {\mathbb F}_9^* \cong C_2 \times C_8$. This last group it is not cyclic: it has order 16, but the order of every element is at most 8.

**Edit**. For an alternative reasoning that $R^*$ is not cyclic, without using the total structure of $R$, note that a cylic group has either 0 or 1 elements of order 2. However, in $R^*$, $2$, $1 + 2\alpha + \alpha^2$, and $2 + \alpha + 2\alpha^2$ all have order 2.

(Of course, this is easier to find once you know that $R \cong {\mathbb F}_3 \times {\mathbb F}_9$, because in ${\mathbb F}_3 \times {\mathbb F}_9$ these are the elements $(-1,-1)$, $(1,-1)$ and $(-1,1)$.
This is also essentially the same argument as the OP gives himself in his answer: $\alpha^4 = 1 + 2\alpha + \alpha^2$.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do you know there exists the isomorphism from $R$ to the product group made from the splitting the polynomial $X^3 + X^2 + 1$ into reducible and irreducible parts ?

Comment: That's by the Chinese Remainder Theorem: $R/(IJ) \cong R/I \times R/J$ when $I$ and $J$ are coprime ideals of the ring $R$. [Added it to the answer as well]

Comment: Ohh, thanks. Guess I have only worked with the CRT in a more practical manner, where I use it to solve linear congruences, but there is a general version of it then ?

Comment: Could you tell me why $R$ is isomorph to $F_3 \times F_9$ ? Does $F_3$ denote $\mathbb Z/ 3\mathbb Z$ here ?

Comment: ${\mathbb F}_3$ denotes, as it does in your question, the field of 3 elements - so it indeed equals ${\mathbb Z}/3$; ${\mathbb F}_9$ is the field of nine elements. The isomorphism ${\mathbb F}_3[X]/(X+2) \to {\mathbb F}_3$ is given by $X \mapsto 1$. The isomorphism ${\mathbb F}_3[X]/(X^2 + 2X + 2) \to {\mathbb F}_9$ is more-or-less by construction: the canonical way of constructing a field of $p^k$ elements is by modding ${\mathbb F}_p[X]$ with an irreducible poynomial of degree $k$.

Comment: So there is no theorem you are using for constructing your isomorphism, they are more or less made of the fly ? Thank you.

Comment: Which isomorphism do you mean? This first one is by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, which I quoted in a previous comment. The second one is by the fact that a that $R/\frak{m}$ is a field for a maximal ideal $\frak{m}$ of a ring $R$; here applied to ${\mathbb F}_3[X]$ and $(X^2 + 2X + 2)$ (and $(X + 2)$ as well, but that's a trivial case).

Comment: I mean how do you just know $\mathbb F_3[X]/(X+2) \rightarrow \mathbb F_3$ given by $X \mapsto 1$, and $\mathbb F_3[X]/(X^2+2X+2) \rightarrow \mathbb F_9$ by construction is well-defined and valid isomorphisms ? Do you use some theorem, or is it just me that doesn't see that right away ?

Comment: The first one is indeed sort-of obvious: we're adding an element $X$ to ${\mathbb F}_3$ and then *intuitively speaking* say (by modding out $X + 2 = X - 1$) that $X = 1$. So we might as well not have added $X$. A full proof is by showing that the kernel of ${\mathbb F}_3[X] \to {\mathbb F}_3$ given by $f(X) = f(1)$ is $(X+2)$.

Comment: For the other one, there is actually some sublety going on. It is a standard theorem that all fields of $p^k$ elements are isomorphic, and that there exists fields of $p^k$ elements, but there is no one-and-only obvious canonical way to create one. (Except when $k = 1$, then ${\mathbb F}_p = {\mathbb Z}/p$ is an obvious way). It is, however, a standard theorem that if you take the quotient of ${\mathbb F}_p[X]$ by an irreducible polynomial of degree $k$, that you then get a field of $p^k$ elements.